# How to open a new window using only one shortcut in gnu screen?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

To open a new screen, I have to do press `Ctrl` + `a`, then `c`, I often found it cumbersome. I would like to do this with only one shortcut, `Alt` + `c`. Also, for moving to previous and next windows, I would like to do them with `Alt` + `h` and `Alt` + `l`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
bindkey \033c screen
bindkey \033h prev
bindkey \033l next
```

in `~/.screenrc`. That assumes terminals that send ESC followed by `x` for <kbd>Alt+X</kbd>.

I have:

```
bindkey \033[6;5~ prev
bindkey \033[5;5~ next
```

For <kbd>Ctrl+PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+PageDown</kbd> (on most terminal emulators).